# C# Mongodb - Get document and matching array elements

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Been stuck on trying to query for a document with ratings and comments in a BsonArray.
The result i am trying to get is the root document and the matching elements in the array that matches a user.

```
    public class Blends
{
    public BsonObjectId _id { get; set;}
    public BsonObjectId GinID { get; set;}
    public BsonObjectId TonicID { get; set;}
    public BsonObjectId GarnishID { get; set;}
    public string GinName { get; set;}
    public string TonicName { get; set;}
    public string GarnishName { get; set;}
    public double Rating { get; set;}
    public double RatingSum { get; set;}
    public double RatingCount { get; set;}
    public List<Reviews> Review { get; set;}
}

    public class Reviews
{
    public int Commentnumber { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int Helpfull { get; set; }
}
```

I have tested many methods, and this only returns 1 match in "Review"

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("GinAndTonic");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Blends>("Blends");
var builder = Builders<Blends>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("Review.User", username);
var fieldsbuilder = Builders<Blends>.Projection;
var fields = fieldsbuilder.Include("Review.$");

var result = await collection.Find(filter).Project<Blends>(fields).ToListAsync();
```

Hope someone can help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
var result = await collection
                .Aggregate().Match(b => b.Review.Any(r => r.User == username))
                .Project(b => new { Review = b.Review.Where(r => r.User == username) })
                       .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Seems to still give me same result, only the first array object that matches the result.